# I want to add a value in array coming from API in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I'm trying to change the **Text** on `Button`.It can be either `"Joined"` or `"Join"`.
Here is the API response.I've to match the `"group_id"` from **GroupUsers**.If it matched then text should be Joined and vice versa.

```
{
    "GroupUsers": [
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "35"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "50"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "49"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "51"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "46"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "48"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "47"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "52"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "40"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "37"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "55"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "56"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "57"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "59"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "60"
        },
        {
            "group_user_status": "1",
            "group_id": "63"
        }
    ],
    "groups": [
        {
            "group_id": "62",
            "group_title": "Hxndhdjdnd",
            "group_type": "Private",
            "group_tags": "Hxnsgsh, gsmsgsu, ",
            "group_icon_image": "uploads/groups/IMG-20200509-WA00142.jpg",
            "group_cover_image": "uploads/groups/IMG-20200509-WA00131.jpg",
            "group_description": "Vdjshskshs",
            "group_created_user_id": "58",
            "group_creation_date": "2020-05-09 23:53:36",
            "group_updation_date": "2020-05-09 23:53:36",
            "followers": "1"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "61",
            "group_title": "Lhzgkxyd",
            "group_type": "Closed",
            "group_tags": "Gkjiif, ifjf, ifc",
            "group_icon_image": "uploads/groups/IMG-20200509-WA00141.jpg",
            "group_cover_image": "uploads/groups/IMG-20200509-WA0013.jpg",
            "group_description": "Fkjfnxpjpfldyg",
            "group_created_user_id": "58",
            "group_creation_date": "2020-05-09 23:46:07",
            "group_updation_date": "2020-05-09 23:46:07",
            "followers": "1"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "58",
            "group_title": "This is APi group",
            "group_type": "Closed",
            "group_tags": "api , resFull api",
            "group_icon_image": "uploads/groups/Screenshot_20200506_180140_com_huawei_android_launcher1.jpg",
            "group_cover_image": "uploads/groups/IMG-20200505-WA00023.jpg",
            "group_description": "Bxdnhdhdf",
            "group_created_user_id": "58",
            "group_creation_date": "2020-05-08 17:29:54",
            "group_updation_date": "2020-05-08 17:29:54",
            "followers": "1"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "54",
            "group_title": "APi group",
            "group_type": "Public",
            "group_tags": "api , resFull api",
            "group_icon_image": "uploads/groups/High-level-overview-of-Docker-architecture7.png",
            "group_cover_image": "uploads/groups/coverbestads-16.jpg",
            "group_description": "This group is created from api request",
            "group_created_user_id": "32",
            "group_creation_date": "2020-05-07 00:07:41",
            "group_updation_date": "2020-05-07 00:07:41",
            "followers": "1"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "53",
            "group_title": "APi group",
            "group_type": "Public",
            "group_tags": "api , resFull api",
            "group_icon_image": "uploads/groups/High-level-overview-of-Docker-architecture6.png",
            "group_cover_image": "uploads/groups/coverbestads-15.jpg",
            "group_description": "This group is created from api request",
            "group_created_user_id": "32",
            "group_creation_date": "2020-05-07 00:05:34",
            "group_updation_date": "2020-05-07 00:05:34",
            "followers": "0"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "50",
            "group_title": "Freelance Pakistan",
            "group_type": "Public",
            "group_tags": "freelance,freelancer,fiverr,guru.com,upwork,peopleperhour",
            "group_icon_image": "uploads/groups/download1.jpg",
            "group_cover_image": "uploads/groups/unnamed.png",
            "group_description": "This is a group related to freelancing . Here you will get all kind of information about getting project on freelancer,fiverr,upwork and guru.com",
            "group_created_user_id": "32",
            "group_creation_date": "2020-02-14 04:03:58",
            "group_updation_date": "2020-02-14 04:03:58",
            "followers": "5"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "49",
            "group_title": "CSS (Federal Service Commission ) Past Papers",
            "group_type": "Public",
            "group_tags": "",
            "group_icon_image": "uploads/groups/css-exam-truehelpers.jpg",
            "group_cover_image": "uploads/groups/css-group-covr.jpg",
            "group_description": "CSS (Federal Service Commission ) Past Papers 2017,2018,2019,2020\r\nCSS Stand for Central Superior Service Exam is conducted by FPSC for the recruitment of BS-17 under the following department.\r\n1.Commerce and Trade Service\r\n2.Custom and Excise Service\r\n3.District Management Group\r\n4.Foreign service of Pakistan\r\n5.Income Tax group  etc",
            "group_created_user_id": "23",
            "group_creation_date": "2020-02-13 22:15:51",
            "group_updation_date": "2020-02-13 22:15:51",
            "followers": "3"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "48",
            "group_title": "BISE Lahore Board Matric Part 1 2, SSC, 9th & 10th Class Past Papers 2020",
            "group_type": "Public",
            "group_tags": "",
            "group_icon_image": "uploads/groups/BISE-Lahore-fa-fsc-result.gif",
            "group_cover_image": "uploads/groups/download.png",
            "group_description": "BISE Lahore Board past paper SSC, Matric Part 1 2, 9th & 10th, Annual & Supply Classes 2020. Download annual and supply biselahore exam old past paper of all 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, SSC, HSSC, FA, FSC, Matric, Inter, Intermediate, SSC Part 1, SSC Part 2, Inter Part 1, Inter part 2, 1st year, 2nd year classes today online from biselahore.com BISE Lahore Board.",
            "group_created_user_id": "23",
            "group_creation_date": "2020-02-13 06:19:07",
            "group_updation_date": "2020-02-13 06:19:07",
            "followers": "2"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "47",
            "group_title": "AIOU B.ED (1.5 years and 2.5 years) Assignments and solved papers 2020",
            "group_type": "Public",
            "group_tags": "",
            "group_icon_image": "uploads/groups/AIOU_(1).jpg",
            "group_cover_image": "uploads/groups/AIOU_(1)1.jpg",
            "group_description": "AIOU B.ED (1.5 years and 2.5 years) Assignments and solved papers 2020",
            "group_created_user_id": "23",
            "group_creation_date": "2020-02-08 23:05:13",
            "group_updation_date": "2020-02-08 23:05:13",
            "followers": "2"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "46",
            "group_title": "Poetry",
            "group_type": "Public",
            "group_tags": "",
            "group_icon_image": "uploads/groups/16508247_1003789546393029_6568778440276501395_n.jpg",
            "group_cover_image": "uploads/groups/16426143_735405959948916_604726409981539585_n.jpg",
            "group_description": "My Best Poetry in World",
            "group_created_user_id": "81",
            "group_creation_date": "2020-02-02 01:20:59",
            "group_updation_date": "2020-02-02 01:20:59",
            "followers": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

here is what I'm tring to do.

```
 await this.props.getGroups(this.state.pageNum);
    if (this.props.isSuccess) {
      this.setState({
        groups: this.props.groups.map(item => {
          this.props.GroupUsers.filter(group_id === item.group_id)
          return {
            ...item,
            joined: false,
          };
        }),

        loading: false,
      });
    }
```

** I want to add joined: false or true in groups array coming from api and storing into state array**

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, this might help you.

```
this.setState({ 
    groups: this.props.groups.map(item => {
      let matchedGroupId = this.props.GroupUsers.filter(
          groupUser => groupUser.group_id === item.group_id
         );
         item.joined = matchedGroupId.length !== 0 ? true : false;
         return item;
      })
   });
```